# Объединить запросы к разным таблицам MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 1 запрос, который получает информацию о пользователе по его `username`:

```
SELECT id, username, avatar, name, description FROM users WHERE username = :username
```

Есть 2 запрос, который получает количество пользователей, подписанных на текущего пользователя:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE user = :username
```

Как я могу объединить эти запросы в один? (PHP 5.6)

Comment: А вы конкретно на sql делаете запросы к базе или это какая-то реализация в коде программы, но ее вы не указали? Просто обычно такое делают отношением OneToMany.

Comment: @Android-EE Да, это реализация в коде программы, программа написана на PHP, используя PDO (если вы про `:username` в запросе).

Comment: Фолловеры записываются за именем пользователя, а не за его id. Плохое решение.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev А чем именно плохое? У пользователей ведь уникальные имена. Можно считать, что это идентификатор.

Comment: Я все же делал бы через отношением один ко многим и при 1 запросе - username, я бы получал сразу в списке всех его подписчиков.

Comment: @phen0men правильнее и лучше записывать за id, чем за именем. При том, что ид автоинкремент. Лишнее дублирование и использование int заместо string(text) в будущем принесёт вам более компактные файлы бд (пусть и не на много, но всё же). Это так, совет. Не поймите не правильно. На строку, всё же, в разы больше памяти выделяется, чем на int.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev Ну, вообще, вы правы. Спасибо за совет :)

Comment: @EgorTrutnev вы безусловно правы. Я убедился в этом только что, когда писал модуль смены имени пользователя. Если пользователь изменит свое имя, то придется в каждой таблице соответствующие данные изменять на новые, что совсем неэффективно. Проще и лучше всего - хранить числовые идентификаторы, которые уникальны и неизменны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для MySQL сработает такой запрос

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  u.`id`,
  u.`username`,
  u.`avatar`,
  u.`name`,
  u.`description`
FROM
  `users` u
  LEFT JOIN `followers` f ON (u.`username` = f.`user`)
WHERE
  u.`username` = :username
GROUP BY
  u.`username`
```

Comment: Запрос неверен. Следует поменять местами таблицы и соответственно изменить секцию отбора.

Comment: тут нужен right join на всякий случай

Comment: @Denis Right Join мало, нужно ещё во where делать отбор по users, а не по followers.\

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Что будет выведено для юзера, у которого НЕТ рефералов?

Comment: @Akina. Согласен. Был не прав :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через подзапрос:

```
SELECT id, 
    username, 
    avatar, 
    name, 
    description,
    ifnull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE user = :username), 0) as followers_count,
    ifnull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE follower = :username), 0) as followings_count
FROM users 
WHERE username = :username
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. А если мне нужно узнать не только количество подписчиков, но и количество подписок пользователя?
Дописывать еще один подзапрос типа:
`ifnull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE follower = :username), 0) as followings_count` или можно сделать как-то поэффективней?

Comment: Второй подзапрос будет достаточно эффективен, чтобы не пытаться искать иные решения.

Comment: @phen0men да, добавьте просто новый подзапрос, в данном случае это удобней, чем 2 раза джойнить таблицы. Подправил запрос.